# Dynamic charts with d3 giving problems with duplicate elements in array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm dynamically loading an array with numbers corresponding to some data. Another array carries the associated name. So it looks something like this when loaded:

```
var dataArray = [10, 150, 206];
var nameArray = [A, B, C];
```

and then it's graphed like so:

```
var xI = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 206])
      .range([0, 270]);
var yI = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain([0,1,2])
        .rangeBands([0,40]);
var chart1 = d3.select('#chart')
      .append('svg')
        .attr('width', '300px')
        .attr('height', '40px')
      .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(25,5)');

    chart1.selectAll('rect')
        .data(dataArray)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr('y', yI)
        .attr("width", xI)
        .attr("height", 5);

    chart1.selectAll('text')
        .data(nameArray)
      .enter().append('text')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', function(d){ return yI(d) + yI.rangeBand()/2.5; })
        .attr('dx', -24)
        .attr('dy', '0.25em')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
        .text(String);
```

Hopefully, you're still following along. Suffice it to say that it runs fine and that there aren't any problems with those arrays.

The problem arises when I have duplicate elements in each array like so:

```
var dataArray = [10, 206, 206];
var nameArray = [A, C, C];
```

The whole chart renders incorrectly presumably because of the duplicate elements.

I feel I've been staring at it too long and haven't been able to come up with a solution. Let me if you need any more information. Any and all ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are mapping the rectangle's y coord you are using the data with the y-axes when you in fact want to use the index. Try this:

```
chart1.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dataArray)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr('y', function(d,i) { return yI(i); } )
    .attr("width", xI)
    .attr("height", 5);
```